# Is dgrid-0.4 expected to work with dstore-1.1?

Tags: dgrid, dstore

I'm trying to get started with some grids using [dgrid](http://dgrid.io/)-[0.4](http://dgrid.io/) and having trouble getting them to talk to a store. My project already uses [dstore](http://dstorejs.io/)-[1.1](https://github.com/SitePen/dstore/releases/tag/v1.1.0) and I was hoping to wire it up to this, however bower informs me that it wants 1.0.x as a dependency. I don't know if my woes are through some other ineptitude or because it really does need the older version. Should it work ever with the current dstore release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time dgrid 0.4 was released, `~1.0` was listed as its dstore dependency in `bower.json` to safeguard against any potential breaking changes in 1.1+.  However, in our testing with dgrid 0.4 and dstore 1.1, it should be safe to use, and we'll be updating the dependency listed in dgrid's `bower.json` for future releases.

If bower presents you with a conflict, it should give you the option of choosing between the dependency dgrid lists, or the other dependency you want (1.1.0).  It should be safe to choose the latter.  You can also store this decision in your `bower.json` with the [resolutions property](https://github.com/bower/bower.json-spec#resolutions).